# Was Adam Sandler's dad dead or did he just go away?

Tags: the-cobbler

Can anyone give us proofs from the movie "The Cobbler" that confirm if his dad was dead in the movie or he just went away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the movie.  But [the synopsis on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3203616/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_pl_syn) says the dad (Abraham) reappears at the end of the movie:

> Max wakes up in Jimmy's barber shop. Jimmy offers him some water and a pickle, stating that pickles help with the transition from one body to another. Max asks how he knew about that. Jimmy takes off his shoes to reveal that **he was Abraham the whole time.** Both elated and angry, Max hugs his dad.

It sounds as though he wasn't dead or gone. He was just in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

In the movie, Max put on the shoes of a dead man and becomes a rotting corpse. He even panics and screams "He's dead. He's dead." When he puts on his father shoes he became a healthy, very much alive, version of his dad.

It was obvious that Jimmy was Max's father in disguise. The pears, pickles, wanting to help.